# Currency datatypes in Pentaho Kettle to load to MS SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion, pentaho-spoon, currency-formatting, pentaho-data-integration

What is the best way to handle currency fields using Pentaho Kettle when the end-goal is to load the data into MS SQL Server?  MS SQL Server has a "money" data type, but this isn't available in Pentaho.  I could convert the column to a string, and then strip out the currency symbol before loading as some sort of floating decimal numeric data type, but that seems manual and I would guess that Pentaho has more sophisticated built in capabilities.

Thanks.

Comment: Just use decimal.

Comment: @scsimon 'decimal' is not a datatype in Pentaho Kettle.  There is a 'BigNumber', but this is not a MS SQL Server recognized datatype so the CREATE TABLE statements will not work...

Comment: well does your currenty need to be more than double precision?

Comment: @scsimon no, but 'BigNumber' is not a MS SQL Server recognized datatype.

Comment: You seem to be unwilling to use different datatypes across these two systems. The recommendation by @scsimon seems like the right approach to me.

Comment: @SeanLange  1. 'decimal' isn't even a specified datatype in Pentaho, 2.  even if I use a "number" data type, SQL doesn't recognize this as a data type when you run ask Pentaho to execute the CREATE TABLES statement, 3. using a decimal-like data type doesn't address the issue of dealing with the  dollar signs for currency fields.  Doesn't Pentaho, being an ETL tool contain functionality to load simple currency datatypes to MS SQL Server without janky workarounds?